# Merging of [xbmc] -> [kodi] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've merged `xbmc` into `kodi`; this means that anyone who tries to use `xbmc` will have to use `kodi` instead.  The point is to keep all these questions together for obvious reasons, but to go forward with the correct current name.

Sort of unfortunately, it means all the questions about XBMC from before the name change are now tagged "kodi".  I don't think this is a big deal, but if anyone can think of a good reason to reverse the merge, please post an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that familiar with the process, but would it be possible to change the old XBMC tags to XMBC-depreciated (or something) and have all tags going forward be XBMC?

Personally, I would prefer to see the old XBMC tags under their own name.  New names often bring a whole host of changes, and things that were true with XBMC, might not be the same with Kodi.

Comment: That's my problem with it too, except I think it is still better to keep them together than apart, since kodi will be *mostly* the same as xbmc; really, it  is no different than a version number change, and we don't have separate tags for `xbmc-10`, `xbmc-11`, etc.    There isn't a good way, tag-wise, to indicate the old questions were really about xbmc without completely separating them (but of course the actual questions will refer to "XBMC").

Comment: My gut reaction is still to keep the separation, but I can see the value to doing it this way.  Maybe just add a note to the tag summary?

Comment: It was actually because of a very in-depth [tag article](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/kodi/info) submitted by {name I can't remember} in "suggested edits" that I noticed this (the edit history credits me instead because I had to cut and paste doing the merge).    The tool-tip does say "Versions < 14.0 were called XBMC," but the summary page truncates this :rolleyes:

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I should have checked that before commenting.  Looks good to me!